# Why CustomClipper is not working suddenly?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm studying clipping image as curve, but CustomClipper is not working suddenly.
Only `clipper` property of `IreneClipper` not works. How can I fix it?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Clock',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue
      ),
      home: IreneClip(),
    );
  }
}

class IreneClip extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.orange,),
      body: ClipPath(
        child: Image.asset('assets/irene.jpg'),
        clipper: IreneClipper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IreneClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0.0, size.height);
    return Path();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Error message

> I/flutter (25014): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY
>   ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ I/flutter
>   (25014): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
>   I/flutter (25014): The _ScaffoldLayout custom multichild layout
>   delegate forgot to lay out the following child: I/flutter (25014):
>   _ScaffoldSlot.body: RenderClipPath#ab20f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT I/flutter (25014): Each child must be laid out exactly once. I/flutter
>   (25014): I/flutter (25014): When the exception was thrown, this was
>   the stack: I/flutter (25014): #0
>   MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout.
>   (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:222:13) I/flutter
>   (25014): #1      MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout
>   (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:230:8)

Flutter doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.472], locale ko-KR)
    • Flutter version 1.0.0 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 5391447fae (5 weeks ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
    • Engine revision 7375a0f414
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\AndroidSDK
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\AndroidSDK
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 31.3.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.5656
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.2)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.io/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.30.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by suddenly. Was that working earlier? Secondly, I ran your code and it doesn't give me the error. Can you add your `flutter doctor -v` result?

Comment: It worked, but it isn't working now. I added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved, `shouldReclip` method must return `true` if you want to hot reload clipping image.

```
class IreneClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height-40);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height-60);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is better to implement it as `oldClipper != this`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it with like:

```
Column(
            children: [
              SafeArea(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Stack(
                        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          // stack overlaps widgets
                          ClipPath(
                            clipper: YOURCUSTOMCLIPPER(),
                            child: Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              height: 140,
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```